# How to get all the outputs of loops outside the loop in PHP?

Tags: php

```
        <?php
        $this->data['cumle'] = 'Bizim evdə 3 mühasib yeddi müəllim var';

        $c = str_word_count($this->data['cumle'], 0,"əöüçşğıÜÖĞIƏŞ123456780");
        for($k = 0;$k<$c;$k++){
            $this->data['word'] = explode(" ",$this->data['cumle']);
            $this->data['suallar'] = $this->Welcome->questions($this->data['word'][$k]);

        foreach ($this->data['suallar'] as $key => $this->data['sual']) {
            extract($this->data['sual']);
            $this->data['model'] = $a_sual."+";
        }

        ?>
```

I want to get the `$this->data['model']` as 1 text in out of `for()` and `foreach()`.
Approximately, it will get as "Who+what+why+when+" value.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to change the following line...

```
$this->data['model'] = $a_sual."+";
```

as this just overwrites the previous value, change the `=` to `.=` to add the new part onto the existing value...

```
$this->data['model'] .= $a_sual."+";
```

It's also best to clear this prior to the loop to stop it having previous values in it (if any)...

```
 $this->data['model'] ='';
```

Comment: and array and implode to avoid trailing plus

Comment: The original question has the trailing + in the required output.